# Google Calendar V3 service account usage in ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am aware of the fact, that I am not the first one asking the question, but I have been searching for a couple of days now and I cannot seem to find a solution to my problem.
So the Thing is I need to have my application set up with a Google account and whenever a user completes an action the application adds an event to the application's Google Calendar without bothering the user for any consent. I need all the authentication for the application's account to be done in the code. I have done some searching and I think that the Google Server to Server communication via service account is the way to go. `https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount`

The thing is I have no idea how to set up the client, get the access token and call the API with it. So far I have installed Google API using composer:

```
{
   "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.3.*",
        "dlu/dlutwbootstrap": "dev-master",
        "google/apiclient": "1.0.*@beta"
    }
}
```

And I have also created a service account from the Google Developer Console, and obtained a Client Id, email and so on. So this brings us to the code:

```
$client = new \Google_Client();

    $clientId = '<MY ID>';
    $service_email = '<THE EMAIL>';
    $myMail = '<MY OTHER MAIL>';
    $keyFile = './data/<NAME OF FILE>';

    $client->setClientId($clientId);
    $client->setApplicationName('Timesheet');

    $key = file_get_contents($keyFile);

    $client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
        $service_email,
        array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'),
        $key));
    $client->getRequestToken();

    $calendar = new \Google_Service_Calendar($client);

    $event = new Event();
    $event->setSummary('Appointment');
    $event->setLocation('Somewhere');
    $start = new EventDateTime();
    $start->setDateTime('2014-11-05T10:00:00.000-07:00');
    $event->setStart($start);
    $end = new EventDateTime();
    $end->setDateTime('2014-11-05T10:25:00.000-07:00');
    $event->setEnd($end);
    $attendee1 = new EventAttendee();
    $attendee1->setEmail('<EMAIL ONE>');
    $attendee2 = new EventAttendee();
    $attendee2->setEmail('<EMAIL TWO>');
    $attendees = array($attendee1, $attendee2);
    $event->attendees = $attendees;
    $createdEvent = $calendar->events->insert('<CALENDAR TO INSERT EVENT INTO>', $event);
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could point out what I`m missing and guide me into using the API properly. Thank you in advance!

Best regards,

Valentin

Comment: I don't think I understand the question.  A service account is an account.   If you just want the users to add events to the service accounts calendar it has access to do that.  If you want to add events to the users calendar you need their permission first.   "whenever a completes"  <-- what do you mean by a

Comment: I meant whenever a USER completes an action. So lets say the user has the following mail: user@gmail.com and he has his own calendar (which we are not interested in). The application is itself authenticated with the email: myapp@gmail.com and has a Google calendar. I want to add events to the calendar of myapp@gmail.com so no user consent is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At long last the answer has been found! The mistake was in the insert call:

`$calendar->events->insert('primary', $event);` is the correct code bit. You need to put `'primary'` as the first parameter instead of an email.

Hope this helps someone! :)